# Transformation from Datawarehouse into Big Data structure

Tags: bigdata, dataset

What are the required stages for transferring data in datawarehouse into big data structure. Are there any tools and methods that support it? 
How to use the schema for such transformation, how to deal with different data types like facts and dimensions for instance. What is the criteria for data separation into machines, indexes or unique keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments transitioning big data sets from on-premises systems to a cloud-based system is cumbersome and fraught with challenges. However, you can use Amazon RedShift:

> Amazon Redshift is a fully managed, petabyte-scale data warehouse
>   service in the cloud. You can start with just a few hundred gigabytes
>   of data and scale to a petabyte or more.

1. The first step is to create a data warehouse is to launch a set of nodes, called an Amazon Redshift cluster.
2. After you provision your cluster, you can upload your data set and then perform data analysis queries. Regardless of the size of the data set, Amazon Redshift offers fast query performance using the same SQL-based tools and business intelligence applications that you use today.

> OR

1. Use a Hadoop environment as the landing zone to pull in data from
   various sources, process it, and transfer the processed data to the
   existing data warehouse or other repositories.
2. Explore scenarios of different ways to implement a landing zone. Learn about the architecture of the zone and the tools and techniques for integrating it with various environments.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Arjun. My question is from different perspective. You already have datawarehouse but because of explosion of data you can no longer use it and you want to transform the data into cloud, for instance. So the question is how to do it?

Comment: Hi avi, I knew this is the problem otherwise who takes a backward step from data warehouse to data structure. And above solution is for that so hadoop provide tools to transform data from warehouse to other repository by acting as a Landing Zone for data.

Comment: Thanks again. Can you please elaborate more on the required steps. For instance, how to use the schema for such transformation, how to deal with different data types like facts and dimensions for instance. What is the criteria for data separation into machines, indexes or unique keys?

Comment: Yup I can but its a cumbersome steps. In IBM we use Amazon Redshift services to do this for big projects. I have included some common steps in above answer if you want to go for that but stiill for more info u can visit their website..

Comment: I am looking for methodology rather than tools. First of all to look at the right way to do it. What are the main issue to look at the whole picture and in detail. And afterwards to the tools... If you can direct me to the specific methodology I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Please remember that my data is already well organized in datawarehouse format and at this stage the data is near bigdata. Quite opposite to the case you mentioned at the beginning of your answer.

Comment: I understood what you are saying I may know a way but i have to read about it. Its interesting, I will get back to you with proper methodology.

Comment: Thanks again. Please take into consideration that we can use more information from the datawarehouse structure and the schema that we don't want to loose in the transformation.

Comment: Yup and for your help as you are new to this community. I think you may want to include all the explanation you have given to me through comments in your question itself. So that others will also have a good idea about your question right now its too broad to gain anyone's inetrest.